# Simple.OData.Client - Unable to invoke Action that accepts entity collection parameter

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, simple.odata

> I get error "The parameter 'wheels' is of Edm type kind 'Collection'.
>   You cannot call CreateCollectionWriter on a parameter that is not of
>   Edm type kind 'Collection'."

Below are details of my setup:

Web API 2.2 OData v4 service : I have defined Action in WheelsController class in my service like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateWheels(ODataActionParameters   parameters)
{
object value;
parameters.TryGetValue("carId", out value);
int carId= (int)value;
parameters.TryGetValue("wheels", out value)
IEnumerable<Wheel> wheels = (IEnumerable<Wheel>)value;
// logic goes here....
return OK();
}
```

In WebApiConfig.cs files, the Action configuration is defined as below:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Car>("Cars");
builder.EntitySet<Wheel>("Wheels");
var action = builder.EntityType<Wheel>().Collection.Action("UpdateWheels");
action.Parameter<int>("carId");
action.CollectionParameter<Wheel>("wheels");
```

**I get success in invoking the above action from RESTClient extenstion in FireFox browser** as POST request to URL "http://localhost/Service/Wheels/UpdateWheels" with Request Body as

```
{"carId":2,
"wheels":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Wheel Front 1","Description":"Front wheel left",   "PositionEnum":"FrontLeft"},
{"Id":2,"Name":"Wheel Front 2","Description":"Front wheel right",   "PositionEnum":"FrontRight"}]
}
```

However, it gives **error** when I try to invoke the above service action using Simple.OData.Client in client application such as

```
public async void TestUpdateWheels(List<Wheel> wheelList)
{
// client is derived from ODataClient from assembly Simple.OData.Client.Core.dll, v4.3.0.0
await client.For<Wheel>()
.Action("UpdateWheels")
.Set(new { carId = 2, wheels = wheelList})
.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

> Error message: The parameter 'wheels' is of Edm type kind
>   'Collection'. You cannot call CreateCollectionWriter on a parameter
>   that is not of Edm type kind 'Collection'.

How can I call successfully the above Action from ODataClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turn out to be a bug in Simple.OData.Client version 4.3.0 when I reported to the project site. For details, visit the link  https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/117

> The new bug fix version 4.7.2 of Simple.OData.Client has fixed the
> issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try out in this way. It works for me in one of my project.

```
public async Task<string> TestUpdateWheels(List<Wheel> wheelList)
{
    string getRules = await client.ExecuteActionAsScalarAsync<string>
     ("UpdateWheels", new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
           { "YourParamater", wheelList}

        });
   return getRules ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting!   I have tried exactly what you mentioned. However this is also failing with same error message.

Comment: You need to put attribute on service action     [HttpPost]
        [ODataRoute("TestUpdateWheels")]
        [ActionName("TestUpdateWheels")] public IHttpActionResult TestUpdateWheels(){}

Comment: As I have written, I am able to invoke the Action from Browser RESTClient but not from Simple.OData.Client app. I have [HttpPOST] attribute already applied to the Action method. As it is bound action, the route attribute is not required to be applied.

Comment: Visit the link for details:  https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/117